# Applying a CSS Declaration to More Than One Element Using nth:child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to apply one CSS declaration to more than one HTML element using `nth-child`?

For example I have a nested list and I want to apply the background colour red to list item 1, green to list items 2 to 4, blue to list items 5 to 8 and yellow to list item 9 using only 4 CSS declaration.

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Our Goal</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Media</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">NLC in the News</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Huh... what are items 1, 2, 4, 5, 8 and 9? What are your 4 CSS declarations? Why such a contrived restriction as to only use `:nth-child()`?

Comment: @BoltClock: I think 1-9 is just each `li` going downwards.

Comment: @thirtydot: Ah, that makes sense. I just noticed there are only 9 of them in total.

Comment: Well...It's actually a CSS drop down menu. The 4 main menus are Home, About, Media and Events and I want to give every category - main menu and its subs a different color when hovered.

Comment: That would create a not really maintainable stylesheet (What if you add a menu option?). When it comes to situations like this, good old classes seem to be more practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 4 outer `li` elements here (Home, About, Media, Events). If these correspond to the 4 CSS declarations (actually *rules*) you're referring to, then `:nth-child()` is only part of the solution:

```css
#nav > li:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}

#nav > li:nth-child(2), #nav > li:nth-child(2) li {
    background-color: green;
}

#nav > li:nth-child(3), #nav > li:nth-child(3) li {
    background-color: blue;
}

#nav > li:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you were looking for a formula to apply to the nth outer `li` and all its sub `li`s, then this would be it:

```css
/* Of course, substitute n with the actual number */
#nav > li:nth-child(n), #nav > li:nth-child(n) li
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BoltClock. That was very helpful, especially the formula. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/infinity/u8zAK/1/) is the complete code and the result.

Comment: @Infinity: No problem. Remember that you can mark an answer accepted by clicking the checkmark. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

### With Subgroups (like you have)

Well, in your case it is easier since they are subgrouped. [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y6nS/).

```css
#nav > li:nth-child(1) {background-color: red;}
#nav > li:nth-child(2), 
#nav > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li {background-color: green;}
#nav > li:nth-child(3), 
#nav > li:nth-child(3) > ul > li {background-color: blue;}
#nav > li:nth-child(4) {background-color: yellow;}
```

### For a Single List (like others might have)

*It would also be possible if it were all one list*, but you need to allow the cascade to help. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y6nS/4/):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav"> 
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Our Goal</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Media</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">NLC in the News</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>   
  <li><a href="#">Events</a></li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
#nav > li:nth-child(1) {background-color: red;} 
#nav > li:nth-child(n+2) {background-color: green;} 
#nav > li:nth-child(n+5) {background-color: blue;} 
#nav > li:nth-child(n+9) {background-color: yellow;}
```

Comment: Re your edit: it's not exactly the best idea to restructure your markup to accommodate CSS's *structural* pseudo-classes :P

Comment: @BoltClock--that was not my point for the edit. My point was to show that had his markup been a single list, the coloring could still have been done as he was desiring. PS: I was trying to get my CSS code to show correctly, how did you get it to not appear as comments?

Comment: @BoltClock--oh, it must be the `<!-- language: lang-css -->` you put in.

Comment: That's right. I mention this in the edit summary: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting You'll have to add these in manually due to [this meta issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions).